# How to make Apache Toree work with Jupyter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, apache-toree

I am trying to work with Apache Three and jupyter, in Mac OS High Sierra. While I am installing everything appropriately with:

`pip3 install --user toree`

when I am trying to install anything with `jupyter toree install` I end up with a message as simple as: `Error executing Jupyter command 'toree': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I have googled the message, end up with abstract searches regarding errors not including toree itself, so how is that solved?

Comment: Ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: Unfortunately, not!